# 2 columns into list and sort in R

Tags: r, list, sorting

Let's say we have two list

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 5)
y <- c(12, 14, 15, 61, 71, 21)
```

I want to combine into a list so that we have 2 column `x` and `y` and values should be in same order.

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 5)
y <- c(12, 14, 15, 61, 71, 21)
```

After you have a list I want to sort it on `y` so the final list looks like

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6)
y <- c(12, 14, 15, 21, 61, 71)
```

I am really new to R. 
I tried `list(x,y)` but it seems to make a

```
list(1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 5,  12, 14, 15, 61, 71, 21)
```

so I was wondering someone could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put them in a `data.frame` first and then use `order`:

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 5)
y <- c(-12, 14, 15, 61, 71, 21)
DF <- data.frame(x, y)

> DF[order(DF$y),]
  x   y
1 1 -12
2 3  14
3 4  15
6 5  21
4 2  61
5 6  71
```

Answer (score 1):

keeping as a list, using `lapply`:

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 2,6,5)
y <- c(12, 14,15,61,71,21)


l <- list(x = x, y = y)

## thelatemail
lapply(l, `[`, order(l$y))

# $x
# [1] 1 3 4 5 2 6
# 
# $y
# [1] 12 14 15 21 61 71
```

a more explicit version of the short one given by @thelatemail above but doesn't preserve the names:

```
lapply(seq_along(l), function(x) l[[x]][order(l$y)])

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 3 4 5 2 6
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 12 14 15 21 61 71
```

or `rapply`:

```
rapply(l, function(x) x[order(l$y)], how = 'list')

# $x
# [1] 1 3 4 5 2 6
# 
# $y
# [1] 12 14 15 21 61 71
```

Comment: `lapply(l, \`[\`, order(l$y) )` for short

Comment: ^^ interesting. nice, very lazy